# LibGDX Sprite Screens not loading graphics, or loading up screens

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I have this issue in my LibGDX project, I essentially can't load up my gamescreen, I am following a YouTube tutorial (link to particular tutorial I'm on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSblkR4K1LU), and I have found that my sprite that is supposed to go on my screen, just it won't load up at all, it just opens, closes then pops this up: http://puu.sh/coxUv/d877d08a83.png, I will admit the only thing I have changed from the video was this:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1F, 1F, 1F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
```

I changed GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT (that was in the video), to GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, because it gave me an error: GL10 cannot be resolved to a variable, does anyone have an idea why, tell me if there is any needed information.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Gamescreen Class:

```
package com.edac.unforgivingunderground;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


public class GameScreen implements Screen{

UnforgivingUnderground game;
OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch batch;

public GameScreen(UnforgivingUnderground game){
    this.game = game;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,1920,1080);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

} 

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1F, 1F, 1F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Assets Class:

```
package com.edac.unforgivingunderground;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;

public class Assets {


public static Texture texture_back;
public static Sprite sprite_back;

public static void load(){

    texture_back = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("logo"));
    texture_back.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    sprite_back = new Sprite(texture_back);
    sprite_back.flip(false, true);
}
```

}

Desktop Launcher:

```
package com.edac.unforgivingunderground.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.edac.unforgivingunderground.UnforgivingUnderground;

public class DesktopLauncher {
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

    new LwjglApplication(new UnforgivingUnderground(), config);
}
```

}

Main Class:

```
package com.edac.unforgivingunderground;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class UnforgivingUnderground extends  Game{

public GameScreen game_screen;

@Override
public void create() {
    Assets.load();

    game_screen = new GameScreen(this);

    setScreen(game_screen);

}
```

Comment: The video you are using is outdated, libgdx has stopped support for open GL 1.0 and many other changes, please enter the rest of your code so we can help.

Comment: I edited the code in, just as a side note I am very new to java, and if I don't understand something, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it crashed (you should post the stack dump) but possibly it's because this line: `Gdx.files.internal("logo")`. Maybe you mean `logo.png` or `logo.jpg`. Also make sure that the image file does really exist on your assets folder.

Also, I belive your `render` method is missing one line.:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1F, 1F, 1F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    Assets.sprite_back.draw(batch);
}
```

That way you'll render your sprite to the screen through the SpriteBatch. In your code you can see that you're not using it.

Comment: what do I do about the GL10?

Comment: I've just realised the sheer idiocy of the previous statement, I later realised that GL is open GL, haha

Comment: Yes, in GL10 are the OpenGL ES version 1.0 constants and methods, in GL20 the version 2.0 ones, and so on. You should use at least GL20 nowadays, that was my mistake. :)